# Java Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

Tags: java

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.openjdk.jol</groupId>
   <artifactId>jol-core</artifactId>
   <version>0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

```
    public class MyObject {
    
    }



    public class ObjectTest {
        @Test
        public  void test1() {
            Layouter l;
            //64位vm对象分布,未启动指针压缩
            l = new HotSpotLayouter(new X86_64_DataModel());
            System.out.println(ClassLayout.parseInstance(new MyObject(),l).toPrintable());
            System.out.println("==============================================");
    
            //64位vm对象分布,启动指针压缩
            l = new HotSpotLayouter(new X86_64_COOPS_DataModel());
            System.out.println(ClassLayout.parseInstance(new MyObject(),l).toPrintable());
        }
    
    }
```

Test1() cannot run normally, error message:
Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

I want to view the memory usage of Java objects in the jvm through the jol-core package of openjdk

Comment: sigkill is terminating request from your OS. It comes from outside your program. It's not an error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like test case runs to the end and JVM process is killed automatically. You could try add below codes to delay the killed time 3 minutes though it is not recommended in unit test.

```
        try {
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(3);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```